# How to use EF.Functions.Format in EF Core query condition

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, entity-framework-core, persian-calendar

I have `BirthDate` column in my `UserBaseInfos` table in SQL Server. I can get month of Persian Calendar in SQL Server by using

```
FORMAT(BirthDate, N'MM','fa-IR')
```

For example

```
SELECT
    BirthDate, FORMAT(BirthDate, N'MM','fa-IR') 
FROM [UserBaseInfos]
```

Also I can use it in a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT
    BirthDate, FORMAT(BirthDate, N'MM', 'fa-IR') 
FROM
    [UserBaseInfos]
WHERE
    FORMAT(BirthDate, N'MM', 'fa-IR') = 5
```

Now I want write this query in EF Core and filter records that Persian date month value is 5. But I get an error :

> Error CS1501 No overload for method 'Format' takes 3 arguments

```
query = query.Where(q => EF.Functions.Format(q.BirthDate, "MM", "fa-IR") == 5);
```

How to write this query in EF Core without fetching data by ToList() and get directly from database on my **IQueriable** query variable?

Comment: Have you tried to follow documentation? [User-defined function mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/user-defined-function-mapping)

Answer (score 0):

Format function doesn't exist in EF Core. To achieve your goal, you can convert birthDate in code or  use FromSqlRaw:

```
var query = dbContext.YourEntity
    .FromSqlRaw("SELECT * FROM YourEntityTable WHERE FORMAT(BirthDate, 'MM', 'fa-IR') = '05'")
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you but I have an IQueriable variable that BirthDate is one of that fields and I want to filter that base on persian month, I can't use FromSqlRaw() on IQueriable query variable.

Comment: Maybe generate a where clause using the standard date that might be a bit too broad but would include all cases where the Persian month could be 5. Then filter the returned results more precisely.